# Apache ignore headers and status codes from Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, apache, docker, lumen

I have app based on Docker and microservices. Angular, MySQL, Lumen + Apache. Unfortunately on Docker my API doesn't send any header or status code. Any response is 200. I tried change HTTP server to NGINX but for nothing. I have no idea how can i fix this issue.

Apache config

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
Listen 8080

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

```
ServerName localhost:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
  <Directory /var/www/html/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4.1-apache

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

#COPY .docker/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip && docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers cache


# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

USER $user

EXPOSE 8080
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      args:
        user: sammy
        uid: 1000
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: backend
    ports: 
    - 8000:8080
    container_name: backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/var/www/html
      - ./backend/.docker/apache.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
      - ./backend/.docker/ports.conf:/etc/apache2/ports.conf
      
    networks:
      - jpk
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: jpk-db
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'jpk'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - jpk
  frontend:
    build:
      args:
        env: prod
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: frontend
    container_name: frontend
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
networks:
  jpk:
    driver: bridge
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://([^.]+\.)?(mysite.com|mysite.local:4200|localhost:4200)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: My first guess is that in your php file you have some file that ends with `?>` plus some blank spaces and/or lines. Those blank lines forces the headers to be sent before Lumen has a chance to set other headers

Comment: @Nathanael I haven't php file like that

Comment: @Zwolin PHP should be responsible for setting the status header, how are you setting the status code in Lumen? are you sure this is not overwritten by any middleware?

Comment: @whyguy For example: return response()->json(['error' => 'Permission denied'], 401);. I'm sure, without docker on artisan serve headers send without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey I found answer for my problem. I need to add line

```
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
```

in my Dockerfile